# resetting state does not change the classnames of html elements in the components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a pathfinding visualizer, and am trying to implement the reset board function.

To visualize the visited nodes, I manually change the class names of the nodes in the grid to alter it's color like so:

```
document.getElementById(
          `node-${node[0]}-${node[1]}`
        ).className = `node shortest`;
```

To reset the board, I set the start and end points to default and re-initialize the grid. However, resetting the grid in this fashion doesn't reset the classnames of the nodes that were changed during the visualiztion function.

The grid render:

```
return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleSetStart} id="setStart">SET START NODE</button>
      <button onClick={onNodeClick}>DIJKSTRA</button>
      <button onClick={handleSetStart} id = "setEnd">SET END NODE</button>
      <button onClick={resetBoard}>RESET BOARD</button>
      <div className="grid-container" id = "grid-container">
        {grid.grid.map((row, rowIdx) => {
          return (
            <div key={rowIdx} className="grid-row">
              {row.map((node, nodeIdx) => {
                return (
                  <Node
                    key={nodeIdx}
                    row={node.row}
                    col={node.col}
                    isStart={
                      compareCoords([rowIdx, nodeIdx], startNode) ? true : false
                    }
                    isFinish={
                      compareCoords([rowIdx, nodeIdx], endNode) ? true : false
                    }
                    onClick={handleOnClickNode}
                    className = "node "
                  />
                );
              })}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

reset call:

```
  const resetBoard = () =>{
    setStartNode([0,0])
    setEndNode([17,36])

    setGrid(initGraph())
  }
```

The `initGraph` function returns an object with the default values.

Am I incorrect in assuming that the rerender from the `setState` should completely reset the html to the initial state?

Comment: In React you can't directly update the `className` that doesn't cause a re-render so no changes are seen unless the context is: updating a state in the same function. But I don't see where are you using your first piece of code? And even then it's better to pass a state as dynamic value to the `className={dynamicClassName}`.

Comment: The first piece of code is just inside a loop that iterates through a list of nodes (the `node` variable). I'll see how I can make the class names dynamic, thanks!